# How to change ftp user password?

Tags: ubuntu, passwords, ftp

I need to change my FTP password, from an Ubuntu server with the command line, can you help me?

Thank you all!

Comment: Which FTP program do you use? Sometimes the credentials are shared by the `passwd` file, so `adduser` and `deluser` would be valid methods to change a user account.

Comment: I'm using filezilla, but I need to change it by console

Answer (score -1):

here ist the documentation from command line arguments:

[FileZilla Command Line Arguments](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Command-line_arguments_(Client))

Looks there is no way from the command line.

Comment: The FTP spec does not allow for ftp clients to instruct servers to change a password. This needs to be done server side, and outside of the FTP protocol. Filezilla is an FTP client, so a red herring.

Answer (score -1):

Generally you would ssh into tbe server (or connect via console) and issue the command "passwd" which will prompt to change your password  or, as root, "passwd username". This will have the side effect of changing your ssh password - assuming you are not using public/private keys.

Note that some FTP servers can be configured to use a different authentication method (but generally use the users Linux password by default). If that is the case we would need to know the name of the FTP server as well as how its configured.

Comment: I haves diferents users for the server access and for FTP access, and when i use "passwd ftpuser" the console show me "?invalid command" ...